# PDO, Selecionar uma consulta com alguns campos, de um determinado usuario e codigo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, pdo

Preciso montar uma consulta onde só terei 5 campos (`STATUS`, `ID_USUARIO`, `PACKED`, `ID_TRANSACAO` e `ENTREGUE`).

Preciso que quando eu tiver mudança de `STATUS` mude em outra tabela, e atualize na atual o campo `ENTREGUE` de "N" para "S" e não realize mais consulta neste que já está entregue.

Ao mesmo tempo, preciso que o `PACKED` identifique quanto será entregue a quantia pois esta pegando como ID ou seja, id 1 corresponde a 30 Chips...

Abaixo meu código de status; não tenho ideia de como fazer essa lógica dar certo.

```
 <?php

require_once("core/config/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction') {

    //CÓDIGO DA NOTIFICAÇÃO
    $code = $_POST['notificationCode'];

    //MONTAMOS A URL PARA PEGAR O STATUS
    $url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/notifications/' . $code . '?email=' . $email . '&token=' . $token;

    //PEGAMOS O STATUS VIA CURL
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $transaction= curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    //SE DER ALGUM ERRO NO NOSSO CURL VAI VIM COMO Unauthorized
    if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){


        exit;//Mantenha essa linha
    }

    $pdo = conectaDB();
                    $get = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pagseguro");
                    $get->execute();

                    $query = $get->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    foreach ($query as $row) {
                            $user =   $row['id_user'];
                            $codigo_transacao = $row['id_transacao'];
                            $codigo = $row['packed'];
                    }


    $entregue = 'S';

    switch ($query->$codigo) {
        case '1':
            $chips = '30.00';
            break;

        case '2':
            $chips = '50.00';
            break;

        case '3':
            $chips = '100.00';
            break;

        case '4':
            $chips = '250.00';
            break;
        }


    //COMVERTE O RERTORNO EM STRING
    $transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);       

    /*
     * STATUS RETORNO         
     * 1 - Aguardando pagamento
     * 2 - Em análise
     * 3 - Paga
     * 4 - Disponível
     * 5 - Em disputa
     * 6 - Devolvida
     * 7 - Cancelada
     */ 

    //PEGAMOS O CÓDIGO DO STATUS
    switch ($transaction->status) {
        case '1':
            $status = 'Aguardando pagamento';
            break;

        case '2':
            $status = 'Em análise';
            break;

        case '3':
            $status = 'Paga';
            $edit2   = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pagseguro SET entregue=:entregue WHERE id_transacao=:id_transacao");
            $edit2->bindValue(':entregue', $entregue);           
            $edit2->bindValue(':id_transacao', $transaction->code);
            $edit2->execute();

           // SECOND CASE
            $update   = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET credits=:credits WHERE username=:user_pagseguro");
            $update->bindValue(':credits', $chips);           
            $update->bindValue(':user_pagseguro', $user);
            $update->execute();
            break;

        case '4':
            $status = 'Disponível';
            break;

        case '5':
            $status = 'Em disputa';
            break;

        case '6':
            $status = 'Devolvida';
            break;

        case '7':
            $status = 'Cancelada';
            break;                      
    }


    //ATUALIZAMOS O STATUS NO BANCO DADOS.
    $pdo    = conectaDB();
    $edit   = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE pagseguro SET status=:status WHERE id_transacao=:id_transacao");
    $edit->bindValue(':status', $status);           
    $edit->bindValue(':id_transacao', $transaction->code);

    $edit->execute();                       
}
?>
```

Comment: Resposta aparentemente simples, mais sua pergunta está meio embaralhada. Poderia enviar um exemplo do que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: @Daniel101 exemplo e um retorno do pagseguro atraves de um xml, mas ja tenho dados da compra registrado no banco, quero alem de atualizar esses dados no bd, levar de uma tabela pra outra o credito, e ao mesmo tempo validando q e so para aquele usuario e para aquela transacao nela tenho o codigo que na qual preciso validar quando ocorrer o retorno do pagseguro, pegar o credito q usuario comprou e inserir na conta dele em outra tabela. no caso na tabela de pagamento preciso fazer uma especie de verificação de qual tipo de pacote ele comprou pois os pacotes estao como id, e preciso passar um valr